# Procedural chain links not working with blender curves

Tags: objects, bezier-curves

I'm trying to make a procedural chain link (by following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4GQzWLY0jPY&t=402s&ab_channel=CGCookie)).

One of the steps required is to add a curve (path) and connect the chain link's curve modifier to that newly added curve.

However, the chain link is instead attaching itself to the very end of the curve. As a result, the curve does not affect the chain link unless you grab the point at the end, in which case the chain link will move very stiffly with the position of that particular point. I feel as though I'm properly following the directions, so I don't understand what my issue could be. Any and all help is very much appreciated.

The first picture is the result I'm getting, and the second picture is the expected result shown in the tutorial video:

[image: results I am getting]
[image: expected results]

Comment: Please attach your simplified blend file to see your setup. Use https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com and paste given code into your question. BTW do you have origins of both objects at the same location? Or try to move your object along x axis.

Answer (score 1):

### Curve Modifier

With origins of both objects at the same place it seems to be working properly.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as if the chain is off the end of the curve, and being projected down a straight-line continuation of the curve, beyond the curve's last control-point.

When you give an object a *Curve* modifier, two things happen:

- (In translation) The object is put into the curve's space. That is to say, the object's origin goes to the same location with respect to the curve's origin, as it was, previously, with respect to the World origin.
- The object is projected along the curve, down the selected (object) *Deform Axis* in the modifier, *in the direction of the curve*.

A convenient way to intuitive results is:

1. Ensure the object's origin is coincident with the curve's origin, so you don't have to think about the offset.
2. Set the *Deform Axis* to the one that will project the object down the curve. That means: ensure the curve's origin is at its *first* control-point; its normal-arrows pointing away from it, to the other end. (You can switch a curve's direction in its Edit Mode *Segments* menu). Similarly, ensure the *Deform Axis* of the object is the one pointing away from the object's origin, down the object's length.

Once you've done that, you can play with moving the object and curve around in Edit and Object modes, to get the feel of how it all works.. and this answer will seem way too wordy.

In this case, the object is an Empty-offset array. It may help to parent the Empty to the object, so they always move together, and futher confusion is not created while you're playing, by the array falling apart.